# What is wrong with this code in string reversal?

Tags: c++, c

In the following piece of code I get the error mentioned below. Please tell me 
Why *p=t gives error here

```
void reverse (char *p)
{
    int length=strlen (p);
    int c=0, i=length/2;
    char *Temp=p+length-1, t;

    while (c<length)
    {
       t=*Temp;
       *Temp=*p
       *p=t; 
       //Gives error as illegal, right operand has type char*
       //Why is the error in the above line?
       c++;
       Temp--;
    }

}
```

Comment: Since c++ is mentioned in tags, here's how to reverse a string using stl: `std::string reversed = string(str.rbegin(), str.rend());`

Answer (score 2):

There is a semi-colon missing:

```
   t=*Temp;
   *Temp=*p ; //--here
   *p=t;
```